# How to interpret this error and what to do? Problem with NA and recode

Tags: r, error-handling, na, missing-data, recode

I have a basic question I want to recode some variables. My code is a bit long and I know a bit ugly. Don't scream or run away, at least it gives me the output I want.

What I want is to recode a variable and set all zeros to twos.
Then I make sure the new variable is numeric.
Next I generate a new variable and set all twos to one.

```
w2_data_tb$v1 <- recode(w2_data_tb$var1, '0' = '2')
w2_data_tb$v1 <- as.numeric(w2_data_tb$v1)
w2_data_tb$v1a <- recode(w2_data_tb$v1, '2' = '1')
```

My variable seems to be fine but I do get always an error from R:
Unreplaced values treated as NA as .x is not compatible. Please specify replacements exhaustively or supply .default

My question is, how can I keep the NAs without getting this error?

I think some might ask what I am trying to do here.
Originally I have a variable with NAs, 1 and 0.
I want to count the zeros. But 0 + 0 is 0 ... That's why I do this workaround. My problem now seems to be the NAs.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is probably not an error just a warning. Try with `recode(w2_data_tb$var1, '0' = 2)`. The issue is hat when recoding to `'2'` you change your var to a character and all values different than 0 get recoded as NA. BTW: If you just want to count the zeros why not doing `sum(var == 0)`?

Comment: Hi, thanks so much. This worked!!!

I seem to do something wrong with your suggestion of using
sum(var == 0)

This doesn't work.

I think the problem is that I have a big data set and this is just part of it.

Comment: Probably my fault. I meant doing something like `sum(w2_data_tb$var1 == 0, na.rm  = TRUE`. This should give you the number of zeros in your variable `var1`. But not sure whether this is the result you are trying to achieve.